# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in Spring project

Tags: spring, maven, exception, dependency-injection, autowired

Somehow, It looks like I have a class which can't be seen by spring. I'm new to the framework and i can't see where is the problem. Is it a problem from the version i used in dependencies or is it another thing ? This is the stack trace:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet spring threw exception
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to load class declared as <mapping class="com.sss.model.Stock.java"/> in the configuration:
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to load class declared as <mapping class="com.sss.model.Stock.java"/> in the configuration:
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.parseMappingElement(AnnotationConfiguration.java:650)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1589)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1568)
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:1047)
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:64)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1542)
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:1035)
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:64)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1477)
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:1023)
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:64)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:588)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:189)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sss.model.Stock.java
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:123)
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.parseMappingElement(AnnotationConfiguration.java:647)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1589)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1568)
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:1047)
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:64)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1542)
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:1035)
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:64)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1477)
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:1023)
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:64)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:588)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:189)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
  <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

 <hibernate-configuration>


 <session-factory>
    <mapping class="com.sss.model.Stock.java" />
  </session-factory>

  </hibernate-configuration>
```

dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.36</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.sss.controller, com.sss.model">
</context:component-scan>
<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view."></property>
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" >
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
    p:password="${jdbc.password}">
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

the class that causes the problem:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="stock")
public class Stock implements Serializable {

private Integer stockId;
private String stockCode;
private String stockName;
public Stock() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="stock_id")
public Integer getStockId() {
    return stockId;
}
public void setStockId(Integer stockId) {
    this.stockId = stockId;
}

@Column(name="stock_code")
public String getStockCode() {
    return stockCode;
}
public void setStockCode(String stockCode) {
    this.stockCode = stockCode;
}

@Column(name="stock_name")
public String getStockName() {
    return stockName;
}
public void setStockName(String stockName) {
    this.stockName = stockName;
}


}
```

Is there anything i should add ?

Comment: Try removing `.java` in your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file (`<mapping class="com.sss.model.Stock" />`).

Comment: i tried it. it doesn't have any effect

Comment: Allocate exception for servlet spring
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sss.model.Stock

Comment: also tried with / instead of .

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sss.model.Stock` error is not in the stacktrace you posted. Did you post the whole stacktrace?

Comment: yes there is. sorry for the bad formatting of the text. i added 2 new lines just on top of class not found exception

Comment: did you really get `ClassNotFoundException: com.sss.model.Stock` without `.java` in the end? Make sure you clean up your project correctly before rebuilding it

Comment: trust me. is not in my best interest not to try everything possible. i really removed the extension and cleaned the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use hibernate mapping file if you are already using annotations in the Entity. Like one of the comments above says, you are mixing up between annotations and xml configuration.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a typo in your hibernate.cfg.xml file.

```
<session-factory>
    <mapping class="com.sss.model.Stock" />
 </session-factory>
```

There is no need of the .java ending.

Comment: still  Allocate exception for servlet spring
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sss.model.Stock
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass

Comment: your Exception says:    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sss.model.Stock.java. What is the Package of your class?

Comment: com.sss.model is the package name

Comment: It feels like you are mixing up annotation based mapping and xml-mapping.
Try to delete the hibernate-configuration-block in your hibernate.cfg.xml. You can let Spring do it for you. (Actually you already told spring to do it useing the @Entity-Annotation)

Comment: ok. so does the hibernate.cfg.xml does have to exist if i'm using annotations?

Comment: I think you can delete it.

Comment: no i can't. i just tried... thank you. that was the problem